# How can I have access to connected components using networkx?

Tags: python, networkx, connected-components

I'm using `networkx.connected_components` to have a list of subgraphs of my main graph, but all it returns is this :

```
<generator object connected_components at 0x000001AC12663820>
```

How can I have access to a list of the connected components?
what should I add to the code below to do this? :

```
G = nx.Graph()
components= nx.connected_components(G)

separated_graphs = list(components)

print(separated_graphs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code above does actually return a blank list as it should (i.e. it evaluates the [generator](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) object).  Instead, `print(components)` outputs the generator object without evaluating it as you noted.

The output for a non-trivial example still may not be what you expect, however, since `nx.connected_components()` returns subsets of nodes and not subgraphs. The [docs for `nx.connected_components()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components) has a nice example showing best practice for actually accessing the subgraphs:

```
S = [G.subgraph(c).copy() for c in nx.connected_components(G)]
```